# Java replace all $ signs from start and end of a string

Tags: java, regex

If I have a string like `$$$ $$$some $ value $$ $$$$` I need an regex that matches all `$` signs from start and end of the string, so after the replacement it should be `some $ value`

I'm trying this regex but I think I'm doing something wrong since it returns some weired value:

```
System.out.println( "Before = " + value );
value = value.replaceAll( "((^$)+|($)+$)", "" );
System.out.println( "After = " + value );
```

Output is:

```
Before = $$$ $$$some $ value $$ $$$$
After = $$$
```

Can anyone help me with an advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` is a [PCRE metacharacter](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003288497.htm), therefore you need to escape it in order to match it literally : `\$`.

However, what you seem to look for is the following regex : `((^[\$\s]+)|([\$\s]+$))`.
This regex matches every literal `$` and whitespace at the beginning and end of a string.

You can test it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/iP9BSt/1)

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the `$` (it's a *boundary matcher* for *the end of a line* per the [`Pattern` JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)). When I change

```
value = value.replaceAll( "((^$)+|($)+$)", "" );
```

to something like (because you must escape the escape in a Java `String`)

```
value = value.replaceAll("((^\\$)+|(\\$)+\\$)", "");
```

I get (as requested)

```
Before = $$$ $$$some $ value $$ $$$$
After =  some $ value
```

Answer (score 0):

The `$` is an [anchor](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#dollar) which should be escaped `\$` if you want to match it as a dollar sign or use it in a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).

If you want to replace the match and do not use the capturing groups you can omit the groups `()` and match from the start of the string `^` one or more times a whitespace character or a dollar sign `^[$\s]` or `|` match a whitespace character or a dollar sign until the end of the string `[$\s]+$`.

[`^[$\s]+|[$\s]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/yLEvi5/1)

```
value = value.replaceAll("^[$\\s]+|[$\\s]+$", "");
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/FWAA72443)